# What does "dollar hotel" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What is the meaning of **dollar hotels** in the following sentence:

> After a couple of days in ***dollar hotels*** and one night in the
>   pokey, I finally landed on my mother’s doorstep.

Source: [*The Vicious Cycle* by Jim B.](http://silkworth.net/bbstories/2nd/238_250.html)

Comment: What's the source of this sentence?

Comment: @stangdon The source was added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow your link, but select "Preface", you'll see that the book was originally published in 1939. It is apparent that, at that time, very cheap hotels could be found which charged one dollar per night. From that comes the phrase "dollar hotel".

Comment: Is there any reference which confirms this?

Comment: +1. Only 50 years earlier, $2 would have gotten you far nicer accommodations. https://books.google.com/books?id=xctBAQAAMAAJ&q=%22dollar+hotel%22&dq=%22dollar+hotel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfhMqT6c_KAhVLdj4KHcZUC_MQ6wEIUzAH

Comment: The Lyceum Magazine, Volume 24 Ralph Albert Parlette - 1914 - 
*Vaudeville people who make the same towns do get rates from the two dollar hotels, usually of a dollar and a quarter a day, and often less. They expect rates, insist upon them, and are out to make money. They don't care who knows it...*

Comment: In 1939, I don't think we're meant to take "dollar hotel" literally. I think the phrase had come to mean "cheap,seedy hotel".

Comment: I really don't get it. Why are you calling them cheap? In [that time](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/11/21/woman-works-75-years-same-company_n_6200026.html) an average wage was as much as $8 a week. I think they were very expensive.

Comment: @LucianSava A [1939 paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1660486/) reports 1938 household income in the U.S. at $2,116, or a little over $40/week. A $1 hotel might be expensive for a poor person, but if you read the story, the author of this quote has some university education and a tenuous middle class existence as a salesman. In 2014, annual U.S. household income was around $52,000, so a room of proportional cost would charge around $25/night, certainly [flophouse territory](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/10/nyregion/thecity/10sro.html)— not even hostels can be found so cheap.

Comment: @LucianSava According to the story, the narrator is broke, so it makes sense.